# I can get the correct results after deleting the index. But after adding the index the result becomes strange in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I am searching for a long time on net. But no use. Please help or try to give some ideas how to achieve this. name='chen5915' is not found, database also has such a record and execution plan also be found, I think no other characters after 'chen5915' because I can query after deleting the index and name='chen5915' is true.

```
select 
(select name = '不改名字不加会班'  from table_name where name = '不改名字不加会班' ) as  a,
(select name = '不改名字不加会班'   from table_name where name like '%不改名字不加会班' ) as  b,
(select name = 'chen5915'  from table_name where   name = 'chen5915' ) as  c,
(select name  = 'chen5915'   from table_name where   name like '%chen5915' ) as  d
```

the result is:

```
a,b,c,d
"t","t",null,"t"
```

Execution plan result:

```
Result  (cost=2735.99..2736.00 rows=1 width=4)
  InitPlan 1 (returns $0)
    ->  Index Only Scan using table_name_name_idx on table_name  (cost=0.43..2.65 rows=1 width=1)
          Index Cond: (name = '不改名字不加会班'::text)
  InitPlan 2 (returns $1)
    ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on table_name table_name_1  (cost=475.90..1365.34 rows=800 width=1)
          Recheck Cond: ((name)::text ~~ '%不改名字不加会班'::text)
          ->  Bitmap Index Scan on table_name_name_gin_idx  (cost=0.00..475.70 rows=800 width=0)
                Index Cond: ((name)::text ~~ '%不改名字不加会班'::text)
  InitPlan 3 (returns $2)
    ->  Index Only Scan using table_name_name_idx on table_name table_name_2  (cost=0.43..2.65 rows=1 width=1)
          Index Cond: (name = 'chen5915'::text)
  InitPlan 4 (returns $3)
    ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on table_name table_name_3  (cost=475.90..1365.34 rows=800 width=1)
          Recheck Cond: ((name)::text ~~ '%chen5915'::text)
          ->  Bitmap Index Scan on table_name_name_gin_idx  (cost=0.00..475.70 rows=800 width=0)
                Index Cond: ((name)::text ~~ '%chen5915'::text)
```

```
pg_encoding_to_char,datcollate,datctype
"UTF8","zh_CN.utf8","zh_CN.utf8"
```

Comment: What is strange about the query results? What does the index have to do with it? What are the contents of your `table_name` table? Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: In `psql` run: `select pg_encoding_to_char(encoding), datcollate, datctype from pg_database where datname = <database_name>` and add results to your question. What was the index you created? What OS and version of same are you running this on? Add answers as update to question. Is `'chen5915'` supposed to be in the table just like that with no other characters after?

Comment: CentOS Linux release 7.7.1908 , postgresql13